# An inequality concerning three positive numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a, b, c$ belong to positive real numbers then prove that 
$$\frac{2}{b+c} +\frac{2}{c+a}+\frac{2}{a+b} \le \frac 1a +\frac 1b +\frac 1c.$$

I applied AM-GM inequalities on both sides but I cant even figure out what to do on left side.

Comment: (a) What did you try? (b) Please improve your formatting, for example replace "<=" by "\leq".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying the inequality between the Arithmetic Mean and the Harmonic Mean  we get:$$\frac{2}{(a+b)}\le\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}{2}=\frac{a+b}{2ab}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{2}{(b+c)}\le\frac{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}{2}=\frac{b+c}{2bc}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{2}{(a+c)}\le\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}{2}=\frac{a+c}{2ac}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\tag{3}$$

On adding (1), (2), and (3) we obtain the required inequality:
$$\frac{2}{(a+b)} +\frac{2}{(b+c)}+\frac{2}{(c+a)} \le \frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b }+\frac{1}{c}$$

Comment: I havent done harmonic mean

Comment: @user354545 : try to prove it then. Just apply AM-GM twice.

Comment: @user354545 - Consider $n$ positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n$. The Harmonic Mean (HM) of $n$ numbers is:
$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{x_n}}$. The Geometric Mean (GM) of $n$ numbers is: $\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdot x_2\dotsm x_n}$. The Arithmetic Mean (AM) of $n$ numbers is: $\frac{x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_n}{n}$. These three means obey the inequality: HM $\le$ GM $\le$ AM. In the question apply HM $\le$ AM with $n=2$ and $x_1=\frac{1}{a}$, $x_2=\frac{1}{b}$ for inequality (1). Now do similar for inequalities (2) and (3).